# Firefox inline-block variable width content does not include scrollbars on windows

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have some code like this:

```css
.list {
      display: inline-block;
      max-height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="list">
      <div>test test test test test</div>
      <div>test test test test test</div>
      <div>test test test test test</div>
      <div>test test test test test</div>
      <div>test test test test test</div>
      <div>test test test test test</div>
      <div>test test test test test</div>
      <div>test test test test test</div>
      <div>test test test test test</div>
      <div>test test test test test</div>
      <div>test test test test test</div>
      <div>test test test test test</div>
</div>
```

On Windows/Ubuntu Firefox each item wraps around and is not displayed on a single line because of the vertical scrollbar that appears.

On Windows/Ubuntu Chrome each item is left on a single line.

If `overflow: auto` is changed to `overflow-y: scroll` then Firefox will show each item on a single line. However, now if my list only contains a few items, a scrollbar will always be visible.

Can someone please help me understand what is going on there? Is there a way to fix this so that Firefox behaves like Chrome without using `overflow-y`?

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ad10cfro/)

Comment: have you tried using `overflow-y: auto;` - when it's set to auto, it will only show a scrollbar when it's needed.

Comment: Yep have tried this. It behaves the same in firefox and text will wrap around.